# Embedly link preview API not working for links with comma

Tags: embedly

We have observed that links with special characters such as commas present in them are not getting scrapped.
eg: https://newsroom.ibm.com/2023-04-12-Consumer-Goods-Companies-Boost-Technology-Budgets-by-34-to-Align-Sustainability-and-Operations-and-Drive-Growth,-Finds-New-Study-by-IBM-and-The-Consumer-Goods-Forum

I tried to encode the comma but it throws a 404 there as well. IS there any specific format in which the commas